# Apache and PHP-FPM slow ( development enviroment)

Tags: mysql, php-fpm, apache2

I have Intel i5 and 8gb ram running Arch linux.

I am trying to optimize my local development environment in order to speedup the pageload ( I develop on Magento that is an heavy php application )
Take care I have not any knowledge about `php-fpm` ...

Recently I have installed PHP-FPM but it is actually slower that mod-php:
Testing with `ab` I can see `php-mod` is 20% faster that `php-fpm`

- How can I tune PHP-FPM to run faster ?
  Consider I need to serve 2/3 request for time as I am the only one to access the local site

Comment: Have you enabled opcode caching and data caching in the app?

Comment: I am testing without cache on purpose to see if what is the impact of php-fpm and the difference with php-mod